# NAT virtio-net network adapter not working on VirtualBox windows guest

Tags: windows, virtualbox, drivers, nat, network-adapter

We are following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/796468), to make the guest machine use the VPN of the host.

However, on a Windows 10 host of VirtualBox 7.0.10, a Windows 2016 guest failed to recognize a network device of NAT Para-virtualized Network (virtio-net).

In the virtual machine's context of "Device Management > Other devices", it shows as a "PCI Device" without any driver information.

The guest machine has two other network adapters working OK, though:

- NAT, type "Intel PRO/10000 MT Desktop ...", and
- Host-only Adapter, name "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter", type "Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop ..."

**Our Question:**

We wonder how to resolve the errors and make the NAT-virtio-net adapter work.

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.